# why my code does not decode the encrypted string based on the dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, encryption, replace

I have a dictionary with keys and values that represent letters.

for example a simple one :

```
DICT_CODE = {'b' : 'g', 'n' :'a', 'p' : 'o', 'x' : 'd', 't' : 'y'}
```

I've received an encrypted code and turned the string into a list, where each item is a word. I need to solve it, according to the items in the dictionary.

an example for a code is :

```
words_list = ["bppx","xnt!"]  # "good day!"
```

I've tried to solve it by using double for loops, as here:

```
 for word in words_list:
     for char in word:
         if char in string.letters:
            word = word.replace(char, DICT_CODE.get(char))
 print words_list
```

expected output -> `["good","day!"]`

output -> `["bppx","xnt!"]`

It does not working at all. the charcaters stay the same and the code is stil unknown.
I don't understand why it isn't working, if someone has time to look and try to help me and see whats wrong, or even suggest a better way (that works).

Comment: `print word_list` will print the `word_list` which you declared above.

Comment: `[''.join(DICT_CODE.get(c, c) for c in s) for s in word_list]`

Answer (score 3):

Changing the `word` variable inside the for loop, would not change the string inside the `word_list`. You would need to remember the index and update the element at that index (and get the word from the index) -

```
for i, word in enumerate(words_list):
    for char in word:
            if char in string.letters:
                    words_list[i] = words_list[i].replace(char, DICT_CODE.get(char))
```

Demo -

```
>>> words_list = ["bppx","xnt!"]
>>> DICT_CODE = {'b' : 'g', 'n' :'a', 'p' : 'o', 'x' : 'd', 't' : 'y'}
>>> for i, word in enumerate(words_list):
...     for char in word:
...             if char in string.letters:
...                     words_list[i] = words_list[i].replace(char, DICT_CODE.get(char))
>>> words_list
['good', 'day!']
```

---

But an easier way for you would be to use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) (along with [`string.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) ). Example -

```
table = string.maketrans('bnpxt','gaody') #First argument characters in your original string, and second argument what they map to.
for i, word in enumerate(words_list):
    words_list[i] = word.translate(table)
```

Demo -

```
>>> import string
>>> table = string.maketrans('bnpxt','gaody')  #This creates the translation table
>>> words_list = ["bppx","xnt!"]
>>> for i, word in enumerate(words_list):
...     words_list[i] = word.translate(table)
... 
>>> print words_list
['good', 'day!']
```

This using list comprehension -

```
words_list[:] = [word.translate(table) for word in words_list]
```

Demo -

```
>>> words_list = ["bppx","xnt!"]
>>> table = string.maketrans('bnpxt','gaody')
>>> words_list[:] = [word.translate(table) for word in words_list]
>>> words_list
['good', 'day!']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't actually modify original list.

```
for i, word in enumerate(words_list):
    for char in word:
        if char in string.letters:
            word = word.replace(char, DICT_CODE.get(char))
            words_list[i] = word

print words_list

['good', 'day!']
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, by @marmeladze, `print word_list will` print the `word_list` which you declared above.

What you want, is something like this:

```
DICT_CODE = {'b' : 'g', 'n' :'a', 'p' : 'o', 'x' : 'd', 't' : 'y', '!': '!'}

words_list = ["bppx","xnt!"]

decoded_list = []

for word in words_list:

    for char in word:    
            word = word.replace(char, DICT_CODE.get(char))
    decoded_list.append(word)

print decoded_list
```

Output

```
['good', 'day!']
```

Hope this helps.